# Vue dynamic calculation on input change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to calculate the earnings from share using vue. I'm subtracting the day closing amount to the start one. I'm not able to display the result on the Dom.

JSfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/4bep87sf/

This is the code:

```
let app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
s: '',
e: '',
tot: '0'
},
watch: {
e: function(){
this.tot = (this.e + this.s);
return this.f;
}
});
```

Comment: This watch interprets to:  "when `e` changes, set `tot` equal to `e` + `s`".  That makes sense, but `return this.f` does not, and also `f` is not defined.  Another issue is you did not show the template, so we can't guess what you intend in the DOM.

Comment: @Dan see the js fiddle for the full code

Comment: I see, that is what I assumed you wanted.  The answer below shows the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`computed` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    s: 0,
    e: 0
  }),
  computed: {
    tot() {
      return Number(this.s) + Number(this.e);
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="s" type="number">
  <input v-model="e" type="number">
  <pre>{{s}} + {{e}} = {{tot}}</pre>
</div>
```

Also note you need to cast your values as `Number()` if you want the sum to be correct. If they're interpreted as strings `a` + `b` = `ab`.

Answer (score 1):

Very close to tao answer. Only "fix" two User experience issues (Not directly related to Vue).

#### Issue 1: "030" or "30" ahhhh:

First, if you set a default value (`0` for example), when the user focuses input and type "3" the output is `03`! (or `30`) ==> **Very annoying** (Especially on mobile).

[image]

Sometimes it's better to set the input value to `null` and show input [placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) (Fix this annoying issue).

#### Issue 2 (No meaning result):

The output `0 + 0 = 0` does not contribute too much to the user. Sometimes it's better to put the sum inside [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).
[image]

`<p v-if="number1 && number2">{{total}}</p>`

### Basic code example

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    number1: {
      type: Number,
      value: null,
      placeholder: "Enter number 1",

    },
    number2: {
      type: Number,
      value: null,
      placeholder: "Enter number 2",

    }
  }),
  computed: {
    total() {
      return Number(this.number1.value) + Number(this.number2.value);
    }
  },
})
```

```css
span{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3></h3>
  <div>
    <label>Number 1:</label>
    <input autofocus v-model="number1.value" type="number" v-bind:placeholder="number1.placeholder">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Number 2:</label>
    <input v-model="number2.value" type="number" v-bind:placeholder="number2.placeholder">
  </div>
  <p>Total:<span v-if="number1.value && number2.value"> {{total}}</span></p>
</div>
```

`v-model.lazy` also sometimes useful for calucations:

> By default, v-model syncs the input with the data after each input
> event (with the exception of IME composition, as stated above). You
> can add the lazy modifier to instead sync after change events. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#lazy